# How to view a text file in a richtextbox without a openfiledialog in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, openfiledialog

I want to open a text file into a richtextbox without using a OpenFileDialog in VB.NET

Comment: `richTextBox1.LoadFile("C:\MyDocument.rtf")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB.NET 2012.  Something like this works

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.RichTextBox1.LoadFile("C:\MyDocument.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Take a look at the RichTextBoxStreamType Enumeration

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.richtextboxstreamtype(v=vs.90).aspx